# Использование функции filter2D() в open cv

Tags: python, opencv, filter

С помощью функции cv2.filter2D() нужно создать фильтр, который находит в изображении только прямые, наклоненные под углом 60 градусов. Примените его к достаточно интересной сцене и выведите результат

```
car = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
kernel = np.ones((5,5))
#cv2.filter2D(src, ddepth, kernel[, dst[, anchor[, delta[, borderType]]]]) 
DST=cv2.filter2D(car, 14, kernel) 
cv2.imshow("DST",DST)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Я немного не осилил документацию и до меня не дошло, как задать именно 60 градусов в данной функции. Буду рад, если кто-нибудь поможет с реализацией и объяснит,как работает anchor в данной функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте ядро (kernel) размером не менее 5x5, заполните его такими значениями, будто через центр нарисована линия  под углом 60 градусов. Значения на линии, задайте положительными, скажем, 2, вне линии поблизости - отрицательными -1, а далеко - нулевыми. Сумма всех значений должны быть в районе 0..1. Пример для 45 градусов:

```
 -1 -1  2
 -1  2 -1 
  2 -1 -1
```

anchor - базовая точка, которая определяется для "сдвинутых" ядер. Сумма произведений значений ядра со значениями источника (свертка) назначается как раз точке с этими координатами относительно ядра в приёмнике.